# Is it possible to use find and replace on a wildcard string in VIM?

Tags: vim, wildcard, replace

For example, I have a bunch of values with a common prefix and postfix, such as:

```
fooVal1Bar;

fooVal2Bar;

fooVal3Bar;
```

In this case, all variable names begin and end with `foo` and end with `Bar`.  I want to use a find and replace using the random variable names found between `foo` and `Bar`.  Say I already have variables `Val1`, `Val2`, `Val3`, and `Val1Old`, `Val2Old`, and `Val3Old` Defined. I would do a find a replace, something along the lines of:

```
:%s/foo<AnyString>Bar/foo<AnyString>Bar = <AnyString> + <AnyString>Old
```

This would result in:

```
fooVal1Bar = Val1 + Val1Old;

fooVal2Bar = Val2 + Val2Old;

fooVal3Bar = Val3 + Val3Old;
```

I hope it's clear what I want to do, I couldn't find anything in vim help or online about replacing with wildcard strings.  The most I could find was about searching for wildcard strings.

Answer (score 70, accepted):

I believe you want

```
:%s/foo\(\w\+\)Bar/& = \1 + \1\Old/
```

explanation:

`\w\+` finds one or more occurences of a character. The preceeding *foo* and following *Bar* ensure that these matched characters are just between a `foo` and a `Bar`.

`\(...\)` stores this characters so that they can be used in the replace part of the substitution.

`&` copies what was matched

`\1` is the string captured in the `\(....\)` part.

Comment: is there a difference between the \w\+ and .*?

Comment: `\w\+` matches one or more in this set: a-zA-Z0-9_ and `.*` matches zero or more of anything.

Comment: Just tried it on the code I wanted to search and replace on, and it worked like a charm.  thanks again!

Comment: If you want to match a fixed number of occurrences you can use `\w\{n,m}` or `\w\{,m}` to match up to a max number of occurrences

Answer (score 9):

You need to capture what you want to save. Try something like this:

```
%s/\(foo\(\w\+\)Bar\);/\1 = \2 \2Old/
```

Or you can clean it up a little bit with `\v` [magic](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/pattern.html#/magic):

```
%s/\v(foo(\w+)Bar);/\1 = \2 \2Old/
```

Answer (score 3):

Replace string with wildcard

```sh
:%s/foo.*Bar/hello_world/gc
```

Here, `.*` handles wildcoard follows regex more info on [regex quantifiers](https://www.rexegg.com/regex-quickstart.html#quantifiers)

```
. - Any character except line break
* - Zero or more times
```